# Is ElasticSearch Auto-Generated Ids sequential?

Tags: elasticsearch

If we do not specify an Id when inserting a document to elasticsearch, the Id is automatically generated. I also understand that the Ids are Flake Ids, which have a predictive pattern.

My question is are these generated Flake Ids sequential enough that I can perform a sort on _id or _uid and be myself sure the results are in the same order as inserted?

Answer (score 6):

The autogenerated `_id` is not sequential. It is an URL-safe, Base64-encoded GUID generated using modified `FlakeID` algorithm. FlakeID is a decentralized algorithm that generates k-ordered unique IDs.

Note that Elasticsearch does not generate the `_id` using the random UUIDs anymore.

See for more details:

- https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/5941
- https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/7531
- https://github.com/ppearcy/elasticflake

Answer (score 1):

Elasticsearch autogenerated _id is random,  not sequential and same is the case for _uid. If you want to sort sequentially, then easy step is enabling _timestamp so _timestamp will have time of document inserted.

But, _timestamp is updated when document is updated. So, you may want to create new date field providing current time manually .

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-timestamp-field.html

Comment: Even if I had a separate timestamp field with milliseconds, there is a chance that I can have multiple documents with same timestamp. IN that scenario, I need a more granular level to sort the documents.

Comment: If that the case, You have to know by yourself which one is written first.

Comment: The ID is now generated with a time based element, but the byte re-ordering causes it not to be sortable by time.  You could write a script field using Painless that would put it back in sortable order and then use that.